# In-line latex fragment position in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, latex

The in-line LaTex equation images are slightly higher than the rest of the font, maybe because of the image borders. This is really a small thing but could it be better aligned at the bottom?

Comment: What is the value of `org-preview-latex-default-process`? You can try setting it to `dvipng`, `imagemagick`, `dvisvgm` (you will also have to installed the appropriate backend in each case), and see if it gets any better. However, preview adds different fonts into the mix and chances are that there is going to be some misalignment in the buffer; however, when you export to PDF it should be perfect, correct?

Comment: @NickD thanks for your reply. The rendering is pretty much the same for `dvipng` and `imagemagick`. When exporting to PDF everything looks perfect. It really is a trivial thing, I just wanted everything to look perfect in the `org-mode` as well :).

Comment: Maybe the `org-format-latex-options` variable can do the trick?

Comment: @MedSaid I had had a look at that. The only thing I changed was the `scale` option. Made it a bit bigger. There is no option for alignment.